# Azure SQL XML Datatype XSD validation

Tags: sql-server, xml, xsd, azure-sql-database, xsd-1.1

From the following thread [Azure XML support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55731299/azure-xml-support) I can see that Azure SQL supports a native XML datatype. However, does anyone know:

- whether an XSD can be associated with the column value for validation of create / update operations; and,
- If "yes" what version of XSD is supported (e.g. 1.0, 1.1 ...etc)

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/xml-schema-collections-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16)? What about the documentation didn't you understand?

Comment: It does support XSD and conformant with the XSD 1.0 standard with some limitations. Sorry, no XSD 1.1 support.  You can up-vote a request for it here: https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/153a9604-7025-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0da0